# Wordpress FTP changes work only in my browser but not on the live website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, ftp, webserver

I wanted to change the "Order now" button to the "View product" one in the WooCommerce product grid so, I added these lines to the funcions.php file in my theme:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';

    return $button;
}
```

The changes work when I open the website in my Google Chrome browser but they don't work in any other browser or device.

It's my first time facing this problem even if I already have done changes to the same functions.php file (to remove the "Add to cart" button and the notifications).

What should I do?

Thank you

Comment: is it possible that you have an active **cache** on your site, and you're logged-in on chrome? I ask because - usually -  cache is not served to logged in users, only to anons. I think you're actually logged in to WP on chrome, and you're visiting the site as anon on any other browser.

Comment: That was a good option but I didn't and the problem didn't present anymore after some hours so I think it was something that had to do with the servers. Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be cache on your live site.
Please check in private window or after hard refresh ctrl+shift+r.